# PHP page doesn't work after open mysqli connection

Tags: php, mysqli

Why my page doesn't work anymore after I added this code in:

```
<?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pw, $db);
    if ($conn == false) {
        die("Es konnte keine Verbindung zur Datenbank hergestellt werden");
    }
?>
```

The error which I get is:

```
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

If I uncomment this code then it works.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` to the beginning of your php file.

Comment: try this `if(!$conn)`

Comment: have you created all the varriable and given value to that ? which you have passed in mysqli_connect () -- give all the necessary value like host name ,username ,password , db

Comment: Check Your username , password and error reporting on

Comment: The values are correct

Answer (score -1):

change your code to this:

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work...

Comment: @xCihat what is your error with my answer ?

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: @xCihat is this the error: `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.` ??

Comment: yes all other php codes are working. At begin, i had an extra file with the code above and then i included in the index file and it worked. Now i added it directly to the index file and it dont work anymor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127531/discussion-between-blueblazer172-and-xcihat).

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this, hope it will work

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work...

Answer (score -2):

First you should check your database connectivity code, recheck the dbconfig php file. assign correct values for config db.

Check Blueblazer172 answer. it will help you.